# Image took from gallery is displayed in different orientation while using phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, android-camera

I'm using Sencha Touch and Phonegap to display a picture recorded with
the camera. When taking a picture on an iphone via cordova2.7.0, the
picture is drawn with the correct orientation. But using samsung s3, the picture will be leant by -90°(only for portrait images).

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 25, 
          destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
         targetWidth: 120,
         targeHeight: 120,
          correctOrientation: true,
          sourceType: source });
```

I use the above code to take picture. 
The portrait images took from camera displays in correct orientation, issue happens only for the portrait images took from the gallery. Is there is any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It simply solved my issue by adding the parameter encodingType. Now the code looks like

```
var encodingType = navigator.camera.encodingType.PNG;
var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
var source = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: encodingType.PNG,
  targetWidth: 120,
  targeHeight: 120,
  correctOrientation: true,
  sourceType: source });
```

Comment: can you please explain little bit on your issue.

Comment: Image orientation get changed of images which are captured by samsung edge S6, A5 camera(default not using cordova plugin). It works fine for screenshot and picure taken by camera(using cordova plugin).

Comment: encodingType.PNG is not defined

Comment: `encodingType` is an enum of `Camera`, so you want to get it with `Camera.EncodingType.PNG` or maybe `navigator.camera.encodingType.PNG`, depending on your framework. It really only is an integer though, so look at [a documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.EncodingType) and use the according value (i.e. `0`for JPEG, `1` for PNG).
With `correctOrientation : true` passed in the options object, the issue is solved with one of the two landscape orientation. So I guess the plugin uses the gyroscope to get a sense of what is "up".

Comment: A little late but it's "EncodingType" for me, not lowercase "encodingType".

Answer (score 5):

It simply solved my issue by adding the parameter correctOrientation. Now the code looks like :

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
correctOrientation: true,
sourceType: source });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with my Samsung Galaxy S5 as well, but switched encodingType from PNG to JPEG (in combination with a targetWidth) and now it has the correct orientation.

One of the commenters on this forum post mentioned it is due being out of memory.
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/camera-wrong-orientation-with-android/8583

```
try {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    this.orientationCorrected = true;
} catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
    this.orientationCorrected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

New update for cordova plugin that solves this issues.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera
```

just re-install the plugin, here is the fixes they published:

**Add orientation support for PNG to Android (closes #45)**

Answer (score 0):

correctOrientation: true, add this its work for me

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Set **allowEdit : true** and **correctOrientation : true** for any device.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
quality: 60,
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
allowEdit: true,
correctOrientatin: true,
encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
targetWidth: 3000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a device specific issue. For example, with the following code:

```
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    correctOrientation: true,
    allowEdit: false,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
};
navigator.camera.getPicture(success,failure,options);
```

This works on a Nexus 5 and orients the returned image properly, however it doesn't work on a Samsung Tab A and the image orientation is not corrected.

My only workaround is to set allowEdit to true as the edited photo is returned in the proper orientation.